# Phonegap app Jquery page scroll not working in iphone 5

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a phonegap app with cordova 2.0 and am jquery mobile for design.
My app is having header , content and footer  as mentioned in screenshot below

[image: My app]

My media content has 1000 lines of contents . Main content is not scrolling in iphone 5 . But scroll works fine with ipad and iPhone 4 .

Comment: Which version of jQuery & jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Hmm, both are very old versions of jQuery Mobile and Cordova - is there a reason for not updating?

Comment: header and footer colour changes when i update query mobile . And there is no guide to directly update my application to latest version

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read this - http://apachecordova.blogspot.co.il/2012/11/who-is-murdering-phonegap-its-jquery.html. 
We were working on a project which was written with jQM, and on the client side there was a poor native app just to show the html content. The project was to convert the native code to PG, and it was only later that we understood that jQM is a bad companion for PG. There were so many side effects, and the application was full of bugs, that we wish we never had started this project. Consider not using jQM or PG (meaning, not together). I know that isn't an answer but I cannot post this as a comment.